Help locating this reference to St. Augustine?
I am looking for a reference to St. Augustine that seems archaic and doesn't correspond to what I'm finding in my search. The reference is from Fr. James L. Meagher's 1906 book How Christ Said the First Mass, reprinted by TAN in 1984, p. 17, footnote #2:

2 S. Augustine, In Epist. Joan, ad Parthos, Tracts 11, n. 111.

As you might guess, it's the last part that is giving me grief: "Tracts 11, n. 111." This reference is provided in a footnote to Fr. Meagher's statement that

... the Temple story and worship carried their [the Jewish faithful's] minds, down to the days of Christ, to his Last Supper, to his atrocious death, to the Catholic Church with her Pontiff, her bishops, her priests, her sacraments and her millions of redeemed souls.


CHURCH FATHERS: Tractates on the Gospel of John (Augustine) lists (and links to text) "Tractates (Lectures) on the Gospel of John", numbered 1 through 124. Perhaps numbers 11 and 111?

I don't think that's it. This reference is to the epistle of John "to the Parthians," i.e. 1 John, which in St. Augustine's writings is a collection of only ten homilies.

In Epistolam Ioannis ad Parthos tractatus decem (= Homilies on the First Epistle of John) contains only 10 (decem) treatises, so the reference is probably to the treatise with Roman numeral "ii" (2) "Homily 2: 1 John 2:12-17", number "iii" (3), "Ubi iam omnes linguæ sonabant, omnes linguæ credituræ ostendebantur." ("Where all tongues were sounding, all tongues were shown to believe."), which seems to fit Meagher's context of the prefiguration by the Old Testament Temple of the New Testament Mass, the continuity/universality (in time, space, & languages) of the divine worship.

Well! I believe you are right. The simplest answers are almost always right. The reprinted text should have read "II, iii", but reads "11, 111." Thank you!
